# Custom Content - MVC and Resources Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, resources

I am starting a brand new site that uses Forms Authentication. Each user is a member of a Company. Each company has a different stylesheet applied to the site, therefore giving a different appearance. I do this by way of applying a custom class in the HTML tag at authentication. Then, CSS files simply look for `.customer #logonname` to style elements.

I am using resources files to handle localisation because customers may speak different languages. This is working and I have this under control. I have each resources file using a custom namespace and this is working quite well in my razor view.

The issue is that different customers want different content to appear. For example, customer 1 wants the logon field label to say "Username", whereas customer 2 wants the same label to say "Logon ID".

I was wondering if resources files would be a good way to do this. I could create separate resources files for each customer (and language), assign a custom namespace to each resources file and then reference that namespace in the view to get the appropriate content. For example, I have two resources files called Customer1.index.resx and Customer2.index.resx. These files hold English translations for each customer. Customer1.index.resx is using a namespace of Customer1.Translation and Customer2.index.resx is using a namespace of Customer2.Translation.

There might be a label in the index view called lblLogon. Customer1.index.lblLogon has a value of "UserName", whereas Customer2.index.lblLogon has a value of "Logon ID". When I use either of these references, the data is coming through fine - eg 
`<div>@Customer1.index.lblLogon</div>` outputs - `<div>UserName</div>`
`<div>@Customer2.index.lblLogon</div>` outputs - `<div>Logon ID</div>`

Is there a way that I can create a "global" namespace at authentication (called Translation) and map that namespace to either Customer1.Translation or Customer2.Translation based on the user's company membership (data returned from the authentication mechanism). Then, my view can just say the following to generate different HTML based on the company.

`<div>@Translation.index.lblLogon</div>`

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Steven Woolston
w: http://www.webdesignwith.net